# Can I use these sites in Korean?

Tags: support, languages, localization

I'm a student in Korea. Can I use Stack Exchange sites in Korean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're welcome to ask and answer questions in English, of course!

You shouldn't, however, write posts in your local language on Stack Overflow. There is a close reason for such kind of questions:

> **Too localized**
>   This question would only be relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the *worldwide audience of the internet*.

Comment: "too localized" is a bit ironic seeing as english is only third by number of native speakers... But the point stands - SO's official language is english, period.

Comment: @Pekka: Number of native speakers != Number of speakers.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing your question is in response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211712/rails---) being closed on StackOverflow.

If you try and formulate your question in as close to English as possible, the SO community will be more than happy to help you out. StackOverflow will not flame you about grammar or punctuation, as long as it's semi-legible.